# Groups with order $p^nq$ with $p$ and $q$ primes.

Tags: group-theory

Show that if $G$ is a group with $|G| = p^nq$, with $p$ and $q$ are primes and $p > q$, then $G$ contains a unique normal subgroup of index $q$.

Comment: Do you have the Sylow theorems? If so, look at a $p$-Sylow subgroup, noting that any subgroup of index $q$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: The congruence condition should force the existence of a normal subgroup right?

Answer (score 2):

As $p$ does not divide $q$, if $n_p$ is the number of Sylow p-subgroups of $G$, then by Sylow: $n_p$ divides $q$, which implies that it is either $q$ or $1$ (as $q$ is prime). But we also have $n_p \equiv 1 \mod{p}$, which means that it is $1$. Hence, $n_p = 1$ and we have a unique p-sylow normal subgroup of $G$.